# Django archive via crontab in production

Tags: python, django, cron, dev-to-production

I'm having trouble getting crontab to execute a site backup, using django-archive.

crontab file:

```
0 5 * * * python ~/SBGBook/gbsite/manage.py archive
```

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/jgates/SBGBook/gbsite/manage.py", line 17, in <module>
       "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
    ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available $
```

The `python manage.py archive` command works great if I'm in the `gbsite/` directory, but there's some sort of path issue here, I'm guessing. This is all running in a venv on a production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the python interpreter from your virtualenv :

```
0 5 * * * /path/to/virtualenv/bin/python ~/SBGBook/gbsite/manage.py archive
```

Comment: That's a great idea, though the above path to python wasn't found

Comment: @DeltaG Not found? What is the path to this interpreter? Can you run it from your CLI and run the command you want to pass to cron? (I suspect a permission issue).

Comment: Obviously the path to YOUR viritual environment will be different! :)

Comment: No issue - just a typo on my part. :)